# How do I check if a number entered is between 1 and 31

Tags: regex, bash, date

I am trying to capture the day of the month from the user and want to check if the day is valid - between 1 and 31. I don't want the user to have to add a leading 0 to single digit days. How do I accomplish this check in a bash if statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the regex:  `/^([012]?\d|3[01])$/`; I leave the bash part to someone else. Also take note that this is a little silly, since `31` is _not_ valid for some months, nor `30` or even `29` for a subset of years.

Comment: @Phrogs: Your regex allows `0` or `00`. To restrict to 1-31 you'd need something like `^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a job for a regular expression!

This is a job for a [conditional expression](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_68.html).

Here's some code to get you started.

```
if [[ $number -lt 31 ]]; then 
    echo $number is less than 31
else 
    echo $number is greater than 31
fi
```

Of course, date validation is far more complex than this. How many days are there in February?

Answer (score 2):

Use the right tool for the job. Regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Any Turing Complete programming language :) In other words, any language with conditional statements. In other words, any programming language :P

Answer (score 2):

Just do a numeric comparison:

```
if (( var >= 1 && var <= 31))
then
    echo "Valid"
fi
```